# Page number of the table of contents in the indexing

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering

In my document page numbers in the contents are correct but when I click the hyperlink of list of tables  and list of figures it goes to the acknowledgement page. Indexing is not proper. What shall I do? I am pasting the code below

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{overcite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
   citecolor=blue,
  filecolor=red,
 linkcolor=blue,
 urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\nonumber{\include{title}}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm plus2mm minus2mm}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\include{dedication}
\include{certificate}
\include{abstract}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Acknowledgement}}}
\include{ack}
\include{contents}
\include{tables}
\include{listfig}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Chapter 1 : Introduction}}}
\include{chap1-Intro}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Chapter 2 : Literature Review}}}
\include{chap2-Literature}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Chapter 3 : Settlement Response of Geosynthetic Reinforced Granular fill Soft Soil}}}
\include{chap3-calculate_w}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Chapter 4 : Determination of Equivalent Shear Modulus $G_e$ value for multilayer Geosynthetic System}}}
\include{chap4-equi_G}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Chapter 5 : Conclusions and Scope for Future Studies}}}
\include{chap5-conclusion}
\fancyhead[CO]{\large{\textbf{Reference}}}
\include{Reference}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code of your overall driver file. However, without any of the files you're `\includ`ing, it's not possible for anyone else to compile the file properly and then determine what's going on with the the incorrect file-internal hyperlinks or with the indexing process.

Comment: I agree with Miko. Could you please specify how you put the LOF and LOT in the TOC? if you do something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LOF} \listoffigures`, try putting `\phantomsection` in front of it (provided by `hyperref`package)

Comment: "\phantomsection in front of it" i.e. in front of \listofffigures and also in front of \listoftables.

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" way to include the List of Figures in the table of contents is to write

```
\cleardoublepage % to get the correct page in the ToC
\phantomsection  % to get a suitable anchor for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
```

An easier way is to load the **tocbibind** package:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

Then the simple `\listoffigures` command will work.